# GeckoFx does not support postMessage in x64 build

Tags: c#, geckofx

I use the following code to call a C# method from JavaScript:

C#:

```cs
geckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener("myEvent", 
    ((string s) => this.showMessage(s)),true);
```

JS:

```js
var event = new MessageEvent('myEvent', 
    { 'view': window, 
      'bubbles': false, 
      'cancelable':   false, 
      'data': 'some data' });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This works perfectly when I use an x86 build (xulrunner and geckoFx), but when I use an x64 build (xulrunner and geckoFx) I get the following Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in
Geckofx-Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.
StackTrace:
at Gecko.SpiderMonkey.JS_GetStringCharsAndLength(IntPtr cx, IntPtr jsString, UInt32& length)
at Gecko.AutoJSContext.ConvertValueToString(JsVal value)
at Gecko.JsVal.ToString() at Gecko.DomMessageEventArgs.get_Message()
at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.OnHandleDomEvent(DomEventArgs e)
in C:\Users\test\Desktop\GeckoFXsource31\Geckofx-Winforms\GeckoWebBrowser.cs:line 1982
at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.Gecko.nsIDOMEventListener.HandleEvent(nsIDOMEvent e)
in C:\Users\test\Desktop\GeckoFXsource31\Geckofx-Winforms\GeckoWebBrowser.cs:line 1878
```

Does anyone know how fix it OR know of another way to transfer my data from gecko to C# code?